# MySQL - Fields Definition

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to turn the result of the database query join with multiple In a result with field definition? like:

```
SELECT  COLUMN_NAME 
       , DATA_TYPE 
       , CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH 
       , NUMERIC_PRECISION 
       , NUMERIC_SCALE 
       , EXTRA 
       , COLUMN_KEY 
       , COLUMN_DEFAULT 
       , IS_NULLABLE 
 FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
 WHERE   table_name = 'TABLE_NAME' 
         AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'DATA_BASE_NAME';
```

When a table is easy. The problem is when the query involves multiple tables.

Edit: Sorry I put the wrong SQL

Answer (score 0):

### UPDATE

*When a table is easy. The problem is when the query involves multiple tables.* so, you are looking for how to retrieve all TABLES in a certain database. am I right?

then, why don't you try this? (some column removed to shorten answer):

```
SELECT  TABLE_NAME
   , COLUMN_NAME 
   , ORDINAL_POSITION
   , DATA_TYPE
   , IS_NULLABLE 
FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE   TABLE_SCHEMA = 'jsheo_test'
ORDER BY TABLE_NAME, ORDINAL_POSITION;
```

I have added `ORDINAL_POSITION` in you query to display column's position in table properly. It's output like this:

```
+------------+-------------+------------------+-----------+-------------+
| TABLE_NAME | COLUMN_NAME | ORDINAL_POSITION | DATA_TYPE | IS_NULLABLE |
+------------+-------------+------------------+-----------+-------------+
| a          | a           |                1 | int       | YES         |
| b          | a           |                1 | int       | YES         |
| test       | name        |                1 | varchar   | YES         |
| test       | age         |                2 | int       | YES         |
| test       | spent       |                3 | int       | YES         |
| test       | gender      |                4 | char      | YES         |
+------------+-------------+------------------+-----------+-------------+
```

### Orig. answer

Sorry. I can't understand your question. below query always return 'database' (even if `DISTINCT` removed. just one row produces). 1 table can't have same column name more than 1.

```
SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE COLUMN_NAME = 'unique'
AND TABLE_NAME = 'database';
```

are you looking for this?

```
SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE COLUMN_NAME = 'unique'
    AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'database'
```